# JavaFX application runs fine in NetBeans (Debugging) but fails when deployed (Class Not Found)

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx

I've finished this project I've been working on but when we deploy it, after the installer installs the application and I try to run it, it errors out with a dialog that says "Class Not Found Package/Class"

This likely is a failure in my Ant Script. I need to know what I'm doing wrong with it so that I can get the project deployed.

### EDIT 1 :

Okay, so a quick test revealed the problem NOT to be with the way the project is being built, but actually with the code for the main class :

This is the code for the main class file :

```
final Options OptionsForm = new Options();
final Game GameForm = new Game();
final Buttons ButtonsForm = new Buttons();
final Stage
    ButtonsStage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT),
    OptionsStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY),
    GameStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
final private static Stage ProgressStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
final private static ProgressDialog progDialog =
    new ProgressDialog("Launching . . . This may take a few minutes.");
static{
    PrizeSweeper.ProgressStage.setOnCloseRequest(
        (WindowEvent WE) -> WE.consume()
    ); PrizeSweeper.ProgressStage.setScene(new Scene(PrizeSweeper.progDialog));
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that the problem is that for whatever reason it doesn't like `static{}` inside the main class. I removed that and it ran fine. I'll leave this here and hope it helps someone else some day.